# Aligning a row matrix near a column matrix

Tags: matrices

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} A =  \begin{matrix}\begin{pmatrix}
  A_{00} \\
  A_{01} \\
  A_{10} \\
  A_{11}
\end{pmatrix}\end{matrix} \begin{pmatrix}
  A^*_{00} & A^*_{01} & A^*_{10} & A^*_{11}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
 \end{document}
```

I want to align the row matrix near the first row of the column vector. How can I do that?

Comment: please always post a full document that shows the problem. Your fragment starts `$\begin{equation}` which generates a Tex error

Comment: Maybe *you* want that, but your readers will be quite puzzled and probably mistake the row vector for an exponent. The right place for the row vector is level with the equal sign.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against doing this: your readers will be quite puzzled and probably mistake the row vector as an exponent to the column vector.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{delarray} % for the wrong kind of alignment

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
  A_{00} \\
  A_{01} \\
  A_{10} \\
  A_{11}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  A^*_{00} & A^*_{01} & A^*_{10} & A^*_{11}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
A =
\begin{gathered}
\begin{array}[t]({@{}c@{}})
  A_{00} \\
  A_{01} \\
  A_{10} \\
  A_{11}
\end{array}
\begin{array}[t]({@{}cccc@{}})
  A^*_{00} & A^*_{01} & A^*_{10} & A^*_{11}
\end{array}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The typesetting in equation (1) is the standard (and non confusing one).

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
A =\begin{pmatrix} A_{00} \\ A_{01} \\ A_{10} \\ A_{11} \end{pmatrix} \begin{matrix} \begin{pmatrix}  A_{00}^* & A_{01}^* & A_{10}^* & A_{11}^* \end{pmatrix}\\[2.8ex] \\ \\\end{matrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
$$
  A = \pmatrix{A_{00}\cr A_{01}\cr A_{02}\cr A_{03}}
      \matrix{\pmatrix{A^*_{00} & A^*_{01} & A^*_{10} & A^*_{11}}\cr\cr\cr\cr}
  \eqno (1)
$$
```

Comment: This code will produce errors if added to the example document in the question. Just a warning for the OP and other readers.

Comment: Of course, the example document itself (without this code) produce errors too. :)

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @dexteritas This is minimal working example. Apply TeX at these five lines and write `\end` or `\bye` in your terminal.